# I don't get ACTION_DOWN on ScrollView

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I get a scroll view, and inside it some linear layout with imageView.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="41"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_red_zone"
        android:id="@+id/scrl_pass"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytPass"
            android:background="@color/light_red_zone"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left" />
    </ScrollView>
```

I add imageView dynamically inside the LinearLayout, and it has a listener

```
                    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            savelog(new Dat_Log_DA(id_tile, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()), id_configurazione));
                            if (semaphoreAudio.tryAcquire()) {
                                play(m1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

that simply start a media player when you touch images.

Then, I need to get the motion Event on the scroll view, so I add a touch listener to the scroll view

```
 scrl_pass = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrl_pass);scrl_pass.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private float mY = 0;
        private static final String tag = "SCROLL VIEW";

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            Log.d(tag, "ACTION " + motionEvent.getActionMasked());
            if ((motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)) {
                mY = motionEvent.getY();
                Log.d(tag, "ACTION DOWN " + mY);
            } else if ((motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) || (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)) {
                Log.d(tag, "Action da " + mY + " a " + motionEvent.getY());
                float currentPosition = scrl_pass.getScrollX();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

the problem is that I get ACTION_MOVE (id=2) and ACTION_UP (id=1), but I don't get the ACTION_DOWN if it's performed on one of that imageviews

Comment: Is there a touch listener on the children too (Linear layout or the ImageView) ?

Comment: no, on imageView just OnClickListener

Comment: Can you implement a touch listener on the ImageView, and see if it catches the DOWN action ?

Comment: I've done, and on ImageView I can catch the DOWN action

Comment: Then, try `scrl_pass.dispatchTouchEvent(event);` as the return value in the ImageView's touch listener. I'm assuming that event is the Event object passed, and that you have already initialized the scrl_pass obj.

Comment: I've try, but starts an infinite loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56124/discussion-between-anudeep-bulla-and-stefano).